# Firebase : Extract data from two table and order

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have two firebase table user_groups and groups like this

[image: user_groups]

and

[image]

I would like to get all group and details of each group for the logged user and display in a list.

I have a service like this :

```
async getGroups() {
const user = await this.authSP.getUserInfo()
return await this.angularFire
  .list('user_groups/'+user.uid)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(groups =>
      groups.map(c => {
        let grps = [];
        this.angularFire.database.ref("groups/"+c.key).once("value", (snapshot) => {
          let value = snapshot.val();
          grps['admin_user_id']=value.admin_user_id;
          grps['name']=value.name;
          grps['photoURL']=value.photoURL
        });

        return {
          '$key': c.payload.key,...c.payload.val(), grps
        }
      })
    )
  )
}
```

In my component :

```
async ionViewWillEnter() {
this.allgroups = []
let GroupsOb = await this.groupSP.getGroups()
GroupsOb.subscribe(groups => {

  this.allgroups = []

  groups.forEach((group) => {
    this.allgroups.push(group)
  })

  this.allgroups.sort(function(a, b) {
      //don't work
      return a.charCodeAt(0) - b.charCodeAt(0);
  });
});
}
```

In my ionic view i have something like this

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let group of allgroups" (click)="goToEditPage(group.$key)" >
        <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <img *ngIf="group.grps.photoURL" [src]="group.grps.photoURL">
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>
        <h2>{{ group.grps.name }}</h2>
        <!--<p>{{ (group.birthdays | async)?.length }} Members</p>-->
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

My code to reorder the data with *this.allgroups.sort* don't work because *a.charCodeAt* is undefined. I tried with *a.grps['name]* but same result.

I think the method to get data from firebase is not good in my service. Does i need to change the service ?

Any help is apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the full code to give you but you should be looking into rxjs library.

You are already using with subscribing to observables.

You have to use the libraries tools to merge together two feeds of data:

- https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html